# Timer reset after 20 seconds but calling a function randomly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

At the moment I am putting together a timer that is supposed to add a movieclip to the stage at a random moment within 20 seconds, but it has to count a full 20 seconds and then reset.

Now like this I can make the timer countdown for a random time up to a maximum of 20 seconds, but it repeats right after that random time. So I was thinking of a Timer delay of 20000 - whatever time the randommath + 20000 has produced. However I can't think of a way to reference the produced time.
Anybody out there who knows of a way to accomplish this? Or maybe a workaround with another method?

Thanks in advance!

```
var treasureclip:MovieClip= new xClip;

var treasureTimer = new Timer(Math.random() * 20000);
treasureTimer.addEventListener("timer", placeTreasure);
treasureTimer.start();

function placeTreasure(evt:TimerEvent):void {
addChild(treasureclip);
Timer(evt.currentTarget).delay = 20000 - //something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

var treasureclip:MovieClip= new xClip;
  /*to check it adds movieClip uncomment this and comment previous
  var treasureclip:MovieClip= new MovieClip;
  with(treasureclip.graphics)
  {
      beginFill(0);
      drawRect(0,0,50,50);
  }*/

var timeout:uint;

startTimeout();
setInterval(startTimeout, 20000);

function startTimeout():void
{
    timeout = setTimeout(placeTreasure, int(20000 * Math.random()));
}

function placeTreasure():void {
    addChild(treasureclip);
}

//Don't forget to kill timeout with clearTimeout(timeout) to avoid memory leaks
```

Comment: I didn't think of the Timeout function, so thanks a lot! However, even though I don't get any errors, the movieclip isn't placed on the stage.. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Also in trace I notice that the function is triggered at a random moment, but once it has triggered, it gets triggered again within the following 20 seconds... Is there a way to use setTimeout to trigger it once in 20 seconds and after the 20 seconds have passed trigger it once in the 20 seconds that follow?

Comment: Edited my post to make stable 20sec intervals. As for isn't placed - check your clip - probably pivot point is wrong or smth, can't say without looking at xClip. Note that the clip wont be duplicated, to duplicate you shell use `addChild(treasureclip = new xClip);`